# AWS Config - MaxNumberOfDeliveryChannelsExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need some advice, i want to create an exception which will ignore AWS Config Delivery channel, if already create. Currently i am getting the following error -

> Failed to put delivery channel 'Security-DeliveryChannel-V156D0TVGUC6'
>   because the maximum number of delivery channels: 1 is reached.
>   (Service: AmazonConfig; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   MaxNumberOfDeliveryChannelsExceededException;

I have written the following code and i need some assistance to write some exception, to ignore the following resource creation if AWS Config - Delivery Channel - already created

```
DeliveryChannel:
Type: 'AWS::Config::DeliveryChannel'
Properties:
ConfigSnapshotDeliveryProperties:
DeliveryFrequency: !Ref DeliveryFrequency
S3BucketName: !If [InternalBucket, !Ref AuditLogBucket, !Ref ExternalAuditLogBucket]
SnsTopicARN: !Ref AuditLogSNSTopic
```

Answer (score 6):

If you ever set up AWS Config via console you have to clean up using AWS CLI.

You can get the status of AWS Config

```
aws configservice get-status
```

And then clean up the recorder and the delivery channel

```
aws configservice delete-configuration-recorder --configuration-recorder-name default
aws configservice delete-delivery-channel --delivery-channel-name default
```

when you're done you should be able to create AWS config through CloudFormation

if you set it up on multiple regions use

```
aws --region us-east-2 configservice ....
```